# sudo ipython - how to launch ipython with sudo power

Tags: python, linux, ipython

I have ipyhon installed in my CentOS6. When I launch ipython without sudo, it works fine. However, one of my python code is writing a new text file. When I do

```
%run writeText.py
PremissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'log.txt'
```

I tried to start ipython with sudo but it did not allow me

```
sudo ipython 
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

which I have double checked ipython is in that directory

Comment: What are the permissions on /usr/bin/ipython ?

Comment: what does `type ipython` output as non root user?

Comment: @tink -rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 230 Aug 2 10:30 /usr/bin/ipython

Comment: @balki If I log in as non root user, it says type: Command not found. Is it the cause?

Comment: I have also noticed that when I tried to launch ipython in root user, it is complaining bash:/usr/bin/ipython: /usr/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory. But I am using python 3.5 (I don't have 3.6 installed) and I don't have any issue launching ipyhton if it is non root account

Comment: What Linux distro are you using, how did you go about installing which versions of python? This is all starting to look like a big mess to me.

Comment: I install 3.5.2 through the source code, and then install ipython through pip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To run sudo command in ipython, I found out I do not necessary need to run ipython with "sudo". Instead, I run ipython and use the magic word "!" to run linux command with sudo access:

```
%ipython
%!sudo lspci
%!sudo ...some command
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume this is because python is not installed for the root user. Try installing ipython for the root user, pointing explicitly to the location of the ipython executable, or adding the location of the python executable to your PATH as root.

Alternatively use `chmod` to change the permissions of that location where you want to write the file, so you can write it as a regular user (without sudo).